# How does entropy change when heat is transfer into a system reversibly with constant $T$?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

My guess will be

$\Delta S_\mathrm{(system)}$ : increase [because heat is flowing into the system]

$\Delta S_\mathrm{(surrounding)}$: decrease [because heat is leaving the environment]

$\Delta S_\mathrm{(universe (sys+surr))}$ : $0$, because it is a reversible process.

Please confirm if my reasonings are correct.
Thank you

Comment: by definition reversibly does not change entropy (remember entropy difference can be zero as well)

Comment: what do you mean by *constant T* in the title ? you must edit the title ( it is : *"... is transfered in a reversible process ?"* ? )

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right.
Entropy of universe or isolated system is always generated (for irreversible process) or equal to zero ( for reversible process)

Entropy of system increase because of heat addition and that of surrounding decreases $\left(-{\frac{\Delta Q}{T}}\right)$.